# Sqlite query problem

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlite

I am having trouble making a query that aims to get the percentage of variation in sales between 2 months.

I have an example in SQL Server that works correctly.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB1 ( SELLMONTH1 INT
                  , SELLMONTH2 INT );

INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES (1000,1250);

SELECT convert(decimal(10,2)
     , (convert(float,(SELLMONTH2 - SELLMONTH1)) / SELLMONTH1) * 100)
FROM TAB1;
```

Returns me 25.00

How to do that same query in SQLite?

I've tried various ways but always returns 0

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show what you've tried in SQLite that didn't work.

Comment: Does this not work? `SELECT 100.000 * (SELLMONTH2 - SELLMONTH1) / SELLMONTH1 FROM TAB1`

Answer (score 2):

Try to `CAST` one of them as `FLOAT` to avoid integer division (From [this thread](http://old.nabble.com/Integer---Numeric-calculations-to4500366.html#a4501777))

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT (SELLMONTH2 - SELLMONTH1) * 100.0 / SELLMONTH1
FROM TAB1;
```

If you specificaly want to cast them as floats (or numeric or whatever), don't use `CONVERT` but `CAST` instead:

```
CAST( sellmonth AS float )
```